# Is current density independent of applied fields for Bloch electrons?

Tags: condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory, hall-effect, quantum-transport, bloch-oscillation

Following Ashcroft-Mermin chapter 12 the semiclassical dynamics is governed by

$
\dot{\vec{r}} = \vec{v}_n(\vec{k}) = \frac{1}{\hbar}\frac{\partial \epsilon_n(\vec{k})}{\partial \vec{k}}
$
and
$
\hbar \dot{\vec{k}} = -e\vec{E} -\frac{e}{c}  \vec{v}_n(\vec{k}) \times \vec{H}
$

In which order one formally should attempt to solve the equations given band structure functions $\epsilon_n(\vec{k})$ and the fields $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{H}$.

Is the velocity independent of the fields and only depends on band structure? If so how one calculates resistances from $\vec{J} = -e \int \frac{d\vec{k}}{4 \pi^3} \frac{1}{\hbar}\frac{\partial \epsilon_n(\vec{k})}{\partial \vec{k}}$ [Eq. 12.16] as they will be independent of fields.

Answer (score 2):

Finite resistance appears when we take into account the collision processes. There are different ways of doing it, e.g.,

- by inserting an ad-hoc dissipative term into the momentum equation:
  $$
  \hbar\dot{\mathbf{k}}=-\frac{\hbar\mathbf{k}}{\tau}-e\mathbf{E}-\frac{e}{c}\mathbf{v}_n(\mathbf{k})\times\mathbf{H}
  $$
- by introducing a probability of resetting the momentum to zero, e.g., as $p(t)=e^{-t/\tau}$
- by integrating the velocity with the Fermi-Dirac distribution function
- by using the equations from the OP in kinetic/Boltzmann equation, e.g.,
  $$
  \mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r},t)=-e\sum_{n,\sigma}\int\frac{d^3\mathbf{k}}{(2\pi)^3}f_{n\sigma}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{k},t)\mathbf{v}_n(\mathbf{k})
  $$
  (The last equation is copied [from here](https://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2010/Winter/physics211b/LECTURES/CH01.pdf), but some of these are definitely covered in Ashkroft&Mermin or any other text on semiconductors.)

If no collisions are included, the, indeed, curious phenomena appear, such as [Bloch oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_oscillation). These are normally not observed in bulk semiconductors, but are easily obtainable in periodic semiconductor nanostructures (superlattices).

A very enlightening calculation can be found in the seminal paper by Esaki and Tsu,
[Superlattice and Negative Differential Conductivity in Semiconductors](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=00ee58b302fdd95b91b4f4f90736b418dedce78c)